# Is there a notepad++ plugin to view and edit html tables?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ which is great, I don't need a WYSIWYG editor but I just started working on a project that is using datatables and it would be a lot easier to be able to add columns in a visual editor. Is there any plugin for notepad++ that does this?

Comment: Are they just plain-text tables or have some special format?

Comment: @martineau Aside from some attributes they are regular tables. I don't mind copying and pasting them into an app to quickly add columns etc.

Comment: What what I've read, Notepad++ has `Column Mode Select` keyboard shortcuts, `Alt-Shft-Arrow keys` or `Alt + Left mouse click` which might be all you need.

Comment: @martineau that just let's me select a specific column area in the source. Not really useful.

Comment: If you do a Google search for "Notepad++ column mode paste" you'll see the column selected can then be pasted.

Comment: @martineau I just watched a video of it's usage, not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding this site http://www.html.am/ which has I believe ckedit on it and lets me easily add / edit the columns and table which I can paste in. Seems to be the only way other than installing dreamweaver.